# When i try to run my global npm package, visual studio code opening

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

Like this. I am trying to run my package, but opening visual code:
[image]

[image]

I tried to write `npx akf-system`, or `npm i akf-system -g` and `asys`.
I want output like this:
[image]

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "akf-system",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "description": "A Node.js based sync system-information (GPU, RAM, etc.) fetcher. Zero dependencies.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node cli.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Akif9748/akf-system.git"
  },
  "author": "Akif9748",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Akif9748/akf-system/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Akif9748/akf-system#readme",
  "bin": {
    "asys": "cli.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A lot of packages have one or more executable files that they'd like to install into the PATH.

> To use this, supply a bin field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. When this package is installed globally, that file will be either linked inside the global bins directory or a cmd (Windows Command File) will be created which executes the specified file in the bin field, so it is available to run by name or name.cmd (on Windows PowerShell).

[From the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)

[Additional read explaining the PATH](https://superuser.com/a/284351/1813923)

So in your case, add to package.json

```
...

    "bin": {
        "akf-system": "cli.js"
    }
...
```

Additionally, I've noticed you tried running cli.js with "node .",
the dot specifies the current directory where node will first look for a package.json or else for an "index.js" file.
If a package.json file would be found, the "main" property will specify the entrypoint of your application. So you could change the main property in your package.json to "cli.js" instead of "index.js"

Comment: I changed it to akf-system, but same result. Visual code opening.

Comment: And the "node ." mistake was a habit, not written in package.json. The main file is index.js, but it is for require() using. cli.js is for cli.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize the core issue. Never came across the issue with vscode opening.
Try adding a shebang line at the beginning of your cli script (#!/usr/bin/env node). Else check whether script exists at C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\akf-system.cmd and make sure the directory is on your system's PATH environment .variable.

Comment: I tried (#!/usr/bin/env node). Nothing changed. I cheched the location. akf-system.cmd, ps1 is here. And dir is on my PATH.
This problem is only occurs with my modules, (my other modules too), other modules (like eslint) not give this problem.

I think it is about to runner, normally it should run with "node" but now it run with "code" (vsc). But i dont know to fix.